# How to replicate PayPal "Completed-Funds-Held" status in Sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'd like to reproduce the "Completed-Funds-Held" status against a Sandbox seller account. I can set the account to "Pending" but unfortunately this seems to be different from "Completed-Funds-Held"

Can anyone clarify how to reproduce this status correctly?

many thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 0):

After contacting PalPal it seems that this option is not available within the Sandbox. Hopefully this will change at some point.